# Using svg.js, how can I access the child nodes of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I am accessing an existing DOM SVG element in my HTML using

```
svgEle = SVG.adopt(svgDocument.getElementById('svg'));
```

How can I access child elements of svgEle without adopting them individually?
I have tried

```
 elementById = svgEle.select("#" + id);
```

and

```
elementById = svgEle.get(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

In SVG.js 3.0+ the API changed and you should use `.find()` or `.findOne()` methods instead of `.select()`.

See reference here: https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/referencing-creating-elements/#using-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

You use [`select(<CSS Selector>)`](http://svgjs.com/referencing/#element-select).

```
svgEle = SVG.adopt(document.getElementById('svg'))

svgEle.select("#keys")
    .stroke('yellow')
```

[`SVG.get(<ID>)`](http://svgjs.com/referencing/#svg-get) only works for SVG elements created by SVG.js.

Here is jsfiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/yy2opz8s/2/

Comment: Thank you, my problem when I had tried to use elementById = svgEle.select("#" + id); was that I had a '.' in the id which does not work.

Comment: pleae note that `select` returns a `SVG.Set`. To get an element of the set you can use `first(), get(index), last()`